Execution failed for task ':webview_flutter_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. on install google_mobile_ads
I give this error:
'Execution failed for task:webview_flutter_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
when install google_mobile_ads package in my Flutter app.
When I run flutter pub add google_mobile_ads and then try to run the app in the Android emulator I have this error.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':webview_flutter_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':webview_flutter_android:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d9e926982c2c139ff9125eb7b6be4144/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d9e926982c2c139ff9125eb7b6be4144/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

I don't know why get this error, because I have java installed.
Thanks for the help!

The problem is that i don't have configured the jdk-dir in flutter
flutter config --jdk-dir /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home

